# Node.js Program Error (Module.js)

Tags: node.js

Hey Guys I have been testing the water with node.js and I wrote a simple web-server program by Ryan Dahl.

```
//web-server.js
var http= require('http');
http.createServer(function(req,res){
   res.writeHead(200, {'content-type':'text/plain'});
   res.end("helo world \n");
});

s.listen(8000);
```

Weirdly, I get this error

[image]

As you can see, the first command is `node-webserver.js`
The second command is where the error is displayed

I do know however that node.js is not broken because the basic introductory program provided on the node.js still works as it is supposed to. Sorry for the massive error screenshot!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's `s.listen(8000)` - a typo?

Comment: What server? You didn't assign anything to `s` variable. Usually it's written as `http.createServer(function(req, res){...}).listen(8000);` (chaining calls).

Comment: tried it...still got the same error
however the error isnt particular to only this program

even this tutorial didnt work
http://simonhampshire.wordpress.com/tag/websockets-node/

Comment: Erm... I'm sorry if it sounds stupid, but what text editor you've used to create this file?

Comment: wordpad :/
i have noticed that notepad adds weird formatting after compilied by node

Comment: Your file is apparently saved as a RTF file, while it needs to be saved as plain text.

Comment: Don't use WordPad to write code. Please. Each time you use it for it, a really cute kitten cries. :(

Comment: @lanzz: miracle it worked...please answer this question so i can accept it as answer

also thanks raina77wow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is apparently saved as a RTF file, while it needs to be saved as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

This is the time when error message actually means something: `{\rtf1\ansi\ansi` is not a valid JavaScript code. And this is the line which was inserted by your text editor.

And, please, please, please, don't EVER use WordPad for editing code. There's plenty of good and free text editors/IDE around here: I personally use [Geany](http://www.geany.org/) for little tasks, and [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) for big projects. I suppose you might try [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#express-web), too (it's free, unlike its bigger brothers). And there's also such a nice thing as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

But using WordPad for writing code is just like using a chainsaw to nail a shelf, in my opinion.